# Testing that an array of objects contains a certain key using Mocha/Chai

Tags: testing, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to write some tests using Mocha and Chai on an array of objects.  I want to go through this array and return any objects that contain the `error` key. I figured this sort of thing would be easy, but I am having a difficult time of it.

```
 [ 
   { fileName: 'font1.ttc', error: 'font_type_not_supported' },
   { fileName: 'font2.ttf', error: 'parse_failed' },
   { fileName: 'font3.tff' } 
 ]
```

I've tried things like.
`expect(testResult).to.have.nested.property('error');`

I'm probably missing something simple, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if `chai` has this as a builtin assertion. Maybe just `expect(testResult.some(e => e.error !== undefined)).to.be.true;`, assuming you're trying to determine whether at least one object in the array has the desired key?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use node function `filter` to do your work.

Something like this works:

```
var array = [
    { fileName: 'font1.ttc', error: 'font_type_not_supported' },
    { fileName: 'font2.ttf', error: 'parse_failed' },
    { fileName: 'font3.tff' }
]
var filter = array.filter(item => item.error != undefined)
```

With this way you get the elements where exists the attribute.

But if you want to compare how many elements has the property, you can use `length` attribute.

```
var count = array.filter(item => item.error != undefined).length
expect(count).gt(0)
```

If `count` variable is greater than 0, implies that at least one object has the attribute.